# if statement variable == null not found with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I stumbled with this if statement and i dont know why doesn't work.

In my firebase database doesn't exists de collection Cuisine.

```
return db.ref('Global/Cuisine').once('value').then(cuisineList =>{
     console.log(`Value cuisineList --> ${JSON.stringify(cuisineList)}`);
     //print Value cuisineList --> null
     if(cuisineList == null){
         console.log(`Doesn't exists`);
         //Do stuff

     }else{
         console.log(`Exists`);
         //do stuff
     }
})
```

and always print `Exists`... why ?, the value of `code` is `null`.
even, when I use other if statement

```
if(!cuisineList)
```

or

```
if(cuisineList === null)
```

print `Exists`.

but... when I get the value of snapshot of firebase it works...

```
return db.ref('Global/Cuisine').once('value').then(snapcuisineList =>{
   let cuisineList = snapcuisineList.val();
   console.log(`Valor cuisineList --> ${JSON.stringify(cuisineList)}`);
   if(cuisineList == null)
        ...
```

outside of the technical explanation of firebase `.val()`, the value is null, why doesn't work?

Comment: try to check `typeof(cuisineList) `

Comment: Can you log what `cuisineList` is? If it is a list, or any object for that matter, they are always `true`, even if empty, and you have to test if it is empty and not if it is `null`

Comment: the cuisineList is null, see the 2nd line of my code.

Comment: Log the variable, not its stringified version, to see the type (or check typeof as @NiVeR suggested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with firebase, but looking at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val), I'd say that you have to use `.val()` to get `null`. And the reason why `JSON.stringify` gives `null` is because [`DataSnapshot` implements `toJson`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#toJSON)

Comment: yeah, that's rigth. thnks, regards